# SELECT: FD_ISSET always returns true in C

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to setup a Client Server program using sockets.

On the server side, I have setup the socket FD correctly , configured it, bonded to port etc. Then I have a while loop that either accepts a new connection or simply prints out a message if it detects one of the accepted connections are ready for reading using select.

On the client side, I am simply connecting to the server, not writing anything.

In general, everything works fine when I have a while loop on the server side (i.e. The server accepts the connection and nothing else happens).

However, when I don't add a while loop to the client, the server continuously detects that the client I have just accepted is ready for reading (even after I have closed the socket on the client side).

Why is it that this happens? I am never writing from the client... Why would it ever be ready for reading, never the less ready AFTER I have closed the client's socket.

Comment: When the socket is closed on the other end, that becomes an EOF on your end. It's readable because EOF is something you can detect by reading.

Comment: When the client closes the connection, the server's socket will select as ready-for-read so that the server can then call recv() (or read()) on the socket, and recv() will return 0 indicating that the connection was closed; then the server can call close() on the socket.

Comment: Thank you, I've been bugging over this for hours..